# 301 redirect to new domain + redirect www to non-www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

i have this .htaccess code for redirecting URL with www to URL without www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now, i would like to add code for redirect whole web to another domain via 301 http code. But I don't want to get redirect loop.

Could I use this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank You.

Comment: Yes, I thought that I don't need it, but i do. Without the second rule, there is not redirect from www.domain.com to domain.com

Comment: How many domains do you have?

Comment: No, it really does not work for www.domain.com.

Comment: What do you mean by how many domains do you have? I want to redirect the olddomain to newdomain.

Comment: Pavel, are you still looking for help with this? If so: do you want to add the redirect to a different domain *additionally* to the existing www-to-naked redirect or was that one just an example and you only need the external redirect?